# Spring boot, declare Service and inject class without annotation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm new with Spring Boot.

I want to separate the domain from the application, so, to do that I need to avoid annotations in the domain layer and I would like to know how to configure a class as a Service (without `@Service` annotation) and inject a class with dependency injection without `@Autowired`?

The domain does not need to know that. I just want to write a configuration for the application and declare my services.

For example I have this query (from CQRS pattern) and I want to configure it as a service inside the application. Same thing with the `@Autowired` annotation.

```kotlin
package fr.rtransat.tvtracker.model.application.query.actor

import fr.rtransat.tvtracker.domain.actor.ActorRepository
import fr.rtransat.tvtracker.domain.actor.exceptions.ActorNotFoundException
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class GetActorByUuidQuery(
    @Autowired
    private val actorRepository: ActorRepository
) {
    fun handle(request: GetActorByUuidRequest): GetActorByUuidResponse {
        val actor = actorRepository.findByUuid(request.uuid)

        if (actor === null) {
            throw ActorNotFoundException(request.uuid)
        }

        return GetActorByUuidResponse(actor)
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at the [`@Bean`  annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) (in particular its usage on a producer method).

Comment: You can use include filters on `@ComponentScan` to include whatever you like. You don't need `@Autowired` on constructors (if it is a single one), so you can ditch that one already. For the rest just write an `@Configuration` with `@Bean` methods to construct what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Which package in spring boot handle this? Any link to register a service in a bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use annotations like `@Autowired` and `@Service` in classes where you don't want to use them. Instead, you can use the configuration class with the annotation `@Configuration`. For example:

```
@Configuration
open class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    open fun getActorByUuidQuery(actorRepository: ActorRepository): GetActorByUuidQuery  {
        return GetActorByUuidQuery(actorRepository)
    }
}
```

This will allow you to keep the class `GetActorByUuidQuery` as a POJO class.